# Problem with derivative of sigmoid activation function

Tags: mathematical-analysis

I'm following Jeff heatons book 'Introduction to Neural Networks with Java'.
To get node deltas, we need to calculate $f'(sum)$. In the very first row for [Training Element #1](http://www.heatonresearch.com/wiki/Backpropagation), we need to compute $f'(1.13) \cdot 0.25$ which Heaton evaluates to $0.045$.

Using my calculator, I get $f'(1.13)=-0.13$ (derivative of sigmoid activation function), then I multiply by $0.25$ to get $-0.0325$. I've been trying to figure out for days how heaton does his calculation but no success yet. Kindly assist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The derivative of a sigmoid is always positive.  Here's my math: `Sigmoid(1.13) = 0.7558`

I computed this on [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sigmoid%281.13%29)

The derivative of a sigmoid `y=S(x)` is `y * (1-y)`, so `0.7558 * 0.2442 = 0.0451`

Comment: Hi,I think what you did is f '( Sigmoid(X) ).What the author did was f '(X)*0.25 and got 0.045

Comment: @LeroyKayanda  If your $f$ is the sigmoid, then MattD is correct. Certainly the fact that he got the same answer as the author is an indicator that his thinking parallels the book. I don't have that book and you haven't said enough to know.

Comment: Hi. Doing F ' ( Sigmoid(X) ) works with training element #1 but not with #2 in ( http://www.heatonresearch.com/wiki/Backpropagation ) . Here's the video that explains the calculation process https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p1-FiWjThs8

Comment: Hey, I finall got it @MattD is right. The derivative of sigmoid $f'(x)=f(x)*(1-f(x))$  Equivalent to $f'(x)$=sigmoid(x)*(1-sigmoid(x)) . What I was doing was $f'(x)=x*(1-x)$ Thanks for the help